Android - Chrome "add to home screen" not in Fullscreen
Is it only me, or does Chrome always opening Links i've added to my Homescreen (3 dot menu on the top right -> Add to home screen) in a new tab?
The Problem occurs only in newest Chrome with Android 12 or higher.
I've testet various Browser with Android 11, 12 and 13.
Conclusion:
Previous Android versions work fine. Another interesting fact is, that im not using PWA. PWA's still open in Fullscreen mode. But my WebApp (non PWA) doesn't open in fullscreen, which is really annoying.
Also weird is, that old Links, added before the Chrome Update, still work.
Any suggestions?

had the same problem. just found out that Samsung browser has the same functionality of creating app like shortcuts. you could try that.

Would only work on devices with the Samsung browser. OP specifically requested help with Chrome.

Samsung browser is installable through play store to most Android phones. OP may appreciate solving the problem in a different way, who are you to assume he specifically wanted to solve it this way.

His question specifically mentions Chrome. I'm not assuming anything, just reading the question.
